# Convert Javascript animation to CSS animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

**Background**

The below code adds to a DIV an animation of different sized floating circles.

The animation works well on desktop browsers, however, on an iPad tablet, all it shows is a static image, no animation.

---

**Question**

What is preventing the code from animating on tablet compared with desktop?

How do I convert the animation in Java Script to an equivalent CSS animation?

---

```js
const colors = ["#000000"];
   const numCircles = 50;
   const circles = [];

   for (let i = 0; i < numCircles; i++) {
     let circle = document.createElement("div");
     circle.classList.add("circle");
     circle.style.background = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
     circle.style.left = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}vw`;
     circle.style.top = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}vh`;
     circle.style.transform = `scale(${Math.random()})`;
     circle.style.width = `${Math.random()}em`;
     circle.style.height = circle.style.width;

     circles.push(circle);
     document.body.append(circle);
   }

   circles.forEach((el, i, ra) => {
     let to = {
       x: Math.random() * (i % 10 === 0 ? -10 : 10),
       y: Math.random() * 10
     };

     let anim = el.animate(
       [
         { transform: "translate(0, 0)" },
         { transform: `translate(${to.x}rem, ${to.y}rem)` }
       ],
       {
         duration: (Math.random() + 1) * 2000,
         direction: "alternate",
         fill: "both",
         iterations: Infinity,
         easing: "ease-in-out"
       }
     );
   });
```

```css
.circle {
   position: absolute;
   border-radius: 100%;
   }
   .box {
   height: 500px;
   width: 500px;
   border: 5px outset red;
   text-align: center;
   }
```

```html
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
   <div class="box">
      <h2>Heading 2</h2>
      <p>This is some text inside a div element.</p>
   </div>
   <p>This is some text outside the div element.</p>
```

---

**Image**

[image]

Comment: I'm not certain @Dai

Comment: @Dai it actually is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate

Comment: @ifthenelse Ahh! I also see it's experimental and not supported by Safari, so that answers OP's question.

Comment: @user4806509 it seems to be supported by mobile Safari, but it's not a stable feature. I would use an animation library, or implement some logic with [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame). You're using random to change the position, so it's not possible to achieve it only via stable css features.

Comment: @ifthenelse `requestAnimationFrame` isn't necessary - all the script does is create elements and set-up a CSSOM animation. I'm writing an answer now.

Comment: @Dai read the compatibility table... animate() is actually supported by Safari and Safari on iOS... but it's still an experimental feature, I wouldn't use it with cross-compatibility in mind.

Comment: @ifthenelse Only since iOS Safari 13.4 though, which was released only a few weeks ago. There are plenty of devices on older iOS versions, including devices that cannot update to iOS 13. I assume the OP might be using an iOS 12 device, for example, or hasn't yet installed the latest update.

Comment: @Dai he's translating each dot by random values. I don't see how it can be done with just pure CSS...

Comment: @ifthenelse It can't be done with *pure* CSS (without server-side logic) - though in my answer the JavaScript is used only to set-up the elements. It uses CSS custom properties to set element-specific variables. The JavaScript itself can be removed entirely if there's server-side rendering that can pre-create the elements and add element-specific styles.

Comment: Thanks all for the discussion, it’s helped frame the issue and solution for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is preventing the code from animating on tablet compared with desktop?

[Your JavaScript code is using `Element.animate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate) which is not currently widely supported by Safari for macOS or Safari for iOS (the minimum version is iOS 13.4, which was only released 2 weeks ago).

> How do I convert the animation in Java Script to an equivalent CSS animation?

You'll still need the script to create all of the `<div>` elements at random positions, but the `animate()` your code uses can be converted to a declarative CSS animation, like so:

You can run this snippet:

Note that I needed add `px` and `s` units to the `--to-x`, `--to-y`, and `duration` values, and I had to disable the `circle.style.transform = 'scale'` CSSOM rule because they were overriding the declarative CSS (the `transform: scale()` isn't needed anyway because the `circle.style.width`/`height` are also randomized.

```js
const colors = ["#000000"];

function createCircles( count ) {
  const circles = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    const circle = document.createElement("div");
    circle.classList.add("circle");
    circle.style.background = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    circle.style.left      = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}vw`;
    circle.style.top       = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}vh`;
/*  circle.style.transform = `scale(${Math.random()})`; <-- This is now disabled */
    circle.style.width     = `${Math.random()}em`;
    circle.style.height    = circle.style.width;

    const toX = Math.random() * (i % 10 === 0 ? -100 : 100);
    const toY = Math.random() * 100;
    const dur = (Math.random() + 1) * 2;
    
    circle.style.setProperty( '--to-x', toX.toFixed(0) + 'px' );
    circle.style.setProperty( '--to-y', toY.toFixed(0) + 'px' );
    circle.style.setProperty( '--duration', dur.toFixed(2) + 's' );

    circles.push(circle);
  }
  return circles;
}

window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', setup );

function setup() {

    const circles = createCircles(50);

    for( const circle of circles ) {

        document.body.append( circle );
    }
}
```

```css
.circle {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100%;

    animation-name: myAnimation;
    animation-duration: var(--duration);
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.box {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 5px outset red;
    text-align: center;
}

@keyframes myAnimation {
    from {
        transform: translate( 0, 0 );
    }
    to {
        transform: translate( var(--to-x), var(--to-y) );
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<div class="box">
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    <p>This is some text inside a div element.</p>
</div>
<p>This is some text outside the div element.</p>
```

This also works **without any JavaScript** if you render the random initial circles into your HTML directly (e.g. using PHP):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <div class="box">
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        <p>This is some text inside a div element.</p>
    </div>
    <p>This is some text outside the div element.</p>

<?php for( $i = 0; $i < 50; $i++ ) { ?>
    <div class="circle" style="left: <?= rand( 0, 100 ) ?>px; top: <?= rand( 0, 100 ) ?>px; width: <?= rand( 0, 50 ) ?>px; height: <?= rand( 0, 50 ) ?>px; --to-x: <?= rand( 0, 50 ) ?>px; --to-y: <?= rand( 0, 50 ) ?>px; --duration: <?= rand( 0, 5 ) ?>s;"></div>
<?php endfor; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much for this. Works both on desktop and tablet now, which was indeed running iOS 12. The explanation of the code changes is really appreciated.